# Hive query logic

Tags: hql

Trying to write an hql which holds a contact_type filed having multiple values for same employee but i need to display any one of it

For example I'm getting the data generated like below and I want only one record with any one of the contact_type out of the below 3 need to be displayed for that Emp_id

```
Emp_id contact_type
111    T
111    M
111    F
```

- T - tel
- M - mob
- F - fax

I tried handling with case but we are not sure which contact types will come for each employee, it may come either 1 or more than 3